# Get current UTC string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way in PHP to calculate the current UTC string? Sometihng that would throw current UTC timestring format on each different server.

In europer it would throw "UTC +1" ... or "UTC 0" ... , "UTC +12:00" always depending on current server settings.

Comment: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and use `format()` on a `DateTime` object

Answer (score 0):

Return UTC timestring on different servers:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
# or
$dt = new DateTime('UTC');

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you have `DateTime` objects in different timezones, you can always get timezone offset by calling `DateTime::getOffset()` who will return offset in seconds; or just use [format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you need:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->getOffset(), " : ", $dt->format('O / P / e / T / Z');
```